# getopt.h missing in aix 7.1

Tags: c++, aix, getopt-long

I am having a hard time figuring out how to add getopt.h in my AIX 7.1. I am using the `getopt_long` function in my code, which I know is in getopt.h instead of unistd.h (which contains `getopt()`).

This code is not compiling in AIX:

```
fatal error: getopt.h: No such file or directory
 #include <getopt.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

Here are the gcc packages installed:

> gcc-4.8.3-1.aix7.1.ppc.rpm
>   gcc-c++-4.8.3-1.aix7.1.ppc.rpm
>   libgcc-4.8.3-1.aix7.1.ppc.rpm
>   gcc-cpp-4.8.3-1.aix7.1.ppc.rpm

I have gone through these links, but they haven't helped much:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unix-getopt.html#sthash.Loz3H0AH.dpuf
- http://www.linuxmisc.com/8-freebsd/eb9bdab1cf6044d5.htm

Also a lot of other web searches.

Am I missing some rpms, or some environment variables?

Comment: I guess `getopt_long` and `getopt_long_only` are GNU-specific functions that might not exist in AIX.

Comment: `getopt_long` is a GNU function.  I don't know if it's any help, but on my Debian Linux machines, `dlocate` reports `libc6-dev:amd64: /usr/include/getopt.h` - i.e. it's part of **GNU libc**.  In the worst case, you may have to resort to an `autoconf` test, and writing an `#ifdef` allowing only short options when it doesn't find `getopt_long()`.

Answer (score 0):

`getopt_long` is GNU-only, but you can take free implementation (for example, [this](https://code.google.com/p/bsd-xdr/source/browse/trunk/src/getopt_long.c?r=11) claims that it is of BSD license, if I understand it right) or write your own implementation (it's not so hard) and use it in your code.

Comment: AIX != GNU. So getopt_long is not native to it. A more authoritative source of a BSD licensed getopt_long is part of FreeBSD (and probably NetBSD) libc: https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/stdlib/getopt_long.c?view=markup

Comment: @Anders "AIX != GNU", yes, I mean it under "`getopt_long` is GNU-only".

Comment: Thanks Vladon and Anders. I ended up coming across https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/index.html#Top which allows GNU extensions to be pulled into non-GNU OSes. One has to download the source code, integrate it into your make / configure infrastructure, and then use it. The compilation of getopt.h worked by following the procedure mentioned in above link. However coz of some other compilation issues I haven't been able to test whether it actually works at runtime!

Comment: I ended up shifting to popt library instead. It is readily available as rpms on Linux and AIX. The code change wasn't much either. I only had to add extra parameters to the options variable to make it compatible to popt.
The rpm for AIX is available on the perzl website - http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Popt